# Fit bounds in which popups will be in vieweble area (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have markers with popups and I want fitBounds that markers popups always be in the viewable area.

---

I have an option to make `fitBounds` with `padding` but I have an issue that padding is discrete.

It mean when i set `{padding:[0,0]}` and `{padding:[30,30]}` I see the same picture like it was with padding = 0.

It starts changing when I increase values (not always) but it does not meet my needs because it set big padding.

Check it at
http://jsfiddle.net/BC7q4/444/

---

Maybe there are some other solutions? Or how Can I change padding more precisely?